# How do I find the route to extend a form?

Tags: 8, forms, routes

I'm using the Content Moderation module in 8.4 and I want to override the `/core/modules/content+moderation/src/Form/EntityModerationForm.php`.

I copied `EntityModerationForm.php` to `/modules/MYMODULE/src/Form/MyEntityModerationForm.php`.

I now want to override `EntityModerationForm` with `MyEntityModerationForm`.

So, following [this tutorial](https://www.foreach.be/blog/how-manipulate-forms-drupal-8), I added a RouteSubscriber to `mymodule.services.yml` and tried to set the route to alter:

```
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
     if ($route = $collection->get('??what_goes_here??')) {
  $route->setDefault('_form', '\Drupal\MYMODULE\Form\MyEntityModerationForm');
     }
```

Examples in the documenation for the routes are `user.login` or `user.logout`.  However, as far as I can tell, `EntityModerationForm.php` does not have a "path"-like route in the same way as `user.login`.

Instead, this form is displayed on entities via the content moderation's `public function entityView()` with this `getForm()` code:

```
    $component = $display->getComponent('content_moderation_control');
    if ($component) {
      $build['content_moderation_control'] = $this->formBuilder->getForm(EntityModerationForm::class, $entity);
    }
  }
```

So I don't know how to alter the route in the RouteSubscriber to use MyEntityModerationForm instead of EntityModerationForm.

Comment: You don't need to alter the route, you need to alter the entity build. [`hook_entity_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/8.4.x) should do the trick

Comment: Also, take a look at hook_form_alter()  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x, might be easier if you are only altering the form a little.